# Mongodb remove all occurence of a string in collection fields

Tags: mongodb

i want to remove all occurrence of non breaking space in MongoDB collection data like  below..

**From**

```
{
"Zip Code" : "&nbsp92606", 
"p_key" : "&nbspUnited States&nbsp"
}
```

**To**

```
{
"Zip Code" : "92606", 
"p_key" : "United States"
}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything that stops you do remove them?

Comment: remove them before storing?